# how to integrate pystache with web.py

Tags: python, web.py, mustache

Now, I  use pystache in web.py in this way:

```
render = render_pystache('templates_dir') 

class index:
    def GET(self):
        render.var('name', 'jim')
        return render.simple()
```

simple.mustache

```
hello, {{name}}!
```

I wrote a render for web.py

render_pystache.py

```
class render_pystache:
    context = {}

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        from pystache import View 
        if self.context:
            t = View(context = self.context)
        else:
            t = View(context = {})
        t.template_path = self.path 
        t.template_name = name
        return t.render

    def var(self, key, value):
        self.context[key] = value
```

Is there any better way to integrate pystache with web.py? for example, how to implement the following function?

```
render.simple({'name' : 'jim'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built an example of integrating pystache with web.py. Have a look here: https://github.com/mattupstate/mustache-with-webpy